# Call TAB and then ENTER keys in an Excel VBA module

Tags: vba, keystroke

I hope I am doing this right. This is my first question on Stackoverflow and I am pretty raw when it comes to Excel.

In the code below I am opening 20 workbooks in succession.
The problem I have is that each workbook requests the user to click "yes" to open as read only or "no" to allow editing. Thus I have to hit "TAB" and "ENTER" (or click "No") for each workbook.

I would like to automatically apply the TAB and ENTER from within the code (hands free)

```
'Name macro
Sub SearchWKBooks()
 
'Dimension variables and declare data types
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim myfolder As String
Dim Str As String
Dim a As Single
Dim sht As Worksheet
 
'Create a new worksheet and svae it to object named WS
Set WS = Sheets.Add
 
'Show dialog box and ask for a folder
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
 
    'Save selected folder path to variable myfolder
    myfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With
 
'Show inputbox and ask for search string to use
Str = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Search string:", Title:="Search all workbooks in a folder", Type:=2)
 
'Stop macro if string is nothing
If Str = "" Then Exit Sub
 
'Save text "Search string:" to cell A1 on worksheet WS
WS.Range("A1") = "Search string:"
 
'Save text in variable Str to cell B1 on worksheet WS
WS.Range("B1") = Str
 
'Save text "Path:" to cell A2 on worksheet WS
WS.Range("A2") = "Path:"
 
'Save text in variable myfolder to cell B2 on worksheet WS
WS.Range("B2") = myfolder
 
'Save text "Workbook" to cell A3 on worksheet WS
WS.Range("A3") = "Workbook"
 
'Save text "Worksheet" to cell B3 on worksheet WS
WS.Range("B3") = "Worksheet"
 
'Save text "Cell Address" to cell C3 on worksheet WS
WS.Range("C3") = "Cell Address"
 
'Save text "Link" to cell D3 on worksheet WS
WS.Range("D3") = "Link"
 
'Save 0 (zero) to variable a
a = 0
 
' The DIR function returns the first filename that matches the pathname specified in variable myfolder and save it to variable Value
Value = Dir(myfolder)
 
'Keep iterating until variable Value is nothing
Do Until Value = ""
 
    'Check if Value is . or ..
    If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
 
    'If Value is not . or .. execute these lines of code
    Else
 
        'Check If file names last three characters match xls or four last characters match xlsx or xlsm
        If Right(Value, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsm" Then
 
            'Enable error handling
            On Error Resume Next
 
            'Open workbook based on path in variable folder and file name in variable Value using password zzzzzzzzzzzz
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfolder & Value, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz"
 
            'Check if an error has occured
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
 
                'Save path to column A based on counter variable a
                WS.Range("A4").Offset(a, 0).Value = Value
 
                'Save text "Password protected" to column B based on counter variable a
                WS.Range("B4").Offset(a, 0).Value = "Password protected"
 
                'Add 1 to the number stored in variable a
                a = a + 1
 
            'Continue here if no error is returned
            Else
 
                'Disable error handling
                On Error GoTo 0
 
                'Go through all worksheets in active workbook
                For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 
                        'Seach worksheet based on value in variable Str and save result to object c
                        Set c = sht.Cells.Find(Str, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
 
                        'Check if object c is not nothing
                        If Not c Is Nothing Then
 
                            'Save address based on range object c to variable firstAddress
                            firstAddress = c.Address
 
                            'Repet following lines between Do and Loop
                            Do
 
                                'Save file name to column A and row number based on variable a
                                WS.Range("A4").Offset(a, 0).Value = Value
 
                                'Save worksheet name to column B and row number based on variable a
                                WS.Range("B4").Offset(a, 0).Value = sht.Name
 
                                'Save cell address to column C and row number based on variable a
                                WS.Range("C4").Offset(a, 0).Value = c.Address
 
                                'Create hyperlink pointing to file name , worksheet name and cell address, show hyperlink text "Link"
                                WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Range("D4").Offset(a, 0), Address:=myfolder & Value, SubAddress:= _
                                sht.Name & "!" & c.Address, TextToDisplay:="Link"
 
                                'Increase count variable a with 1
                                a = a + 1
 
                                'Find next cell that matches and save to object c
                                Set c = sht.Cells.FindNext(c)
 
                            'Keep iterating until c is nothing and c is not equal to the first found cell in the same worksheet
                            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                        End If
 
                'Continue with next worksheet
                Next sht
            End If
 
            'Close workbook and do not save any changes made
            ' GIO Workbooks(Value).Close False
 
            'Diable error handling
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
 
    'Find next file
    Value = Dir
 
'Keep iterating
Loop
 
'Change cell widths to fit text
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `ReadOnly:=True` to your `Workbooks.Open` call?

Comment: `Value` and `Str` are reserved key words of VBA. Using them as variable names is creating confusion if not courting trouble. `c` is a variable you use that needs being declared `As Range`. There should be no question about opening the file. So, limit your focus on the line `Workbooks.Open`. Perhaps the file is already open, in which case you can try `Set` first. Or you might try @GSerg's suggestion in the comment above or both.

Comment: @Variatus `There should be no question about opening the file` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.readonlyrecommended#remarks

Comment: Thanks Guys but perhaps you need to understand that when I say raw I mean really raw. I know close to nothing about VBA. The script above was from another help forum. All I could figure out was how to stop the files from being closed automatically. I tried adding "ReadOnly:=True" but with no luck (error "Expected end of statement

Comment: You just put it at the end of the line, without the comma?..

Comment: Ok I removed the comma now there is no error but I still get the dialog box where I need to tab enter.
I tried adding a space but there was no change.

Comment: So I managed to get it working by adding "Application.SendKeys ("{TAB}{Enter}")"
Before the workbook open call.